# Swift: The tableView do not reload data after press button in alert view

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, ios7, uialertview

I have add the alert view which let user to control that they can delete the all items in their database, but the table do not reload the data again.

I have tried `self.tableView.delegate = self` and `self.tableView.reloadData()`, but it does not work.

Here is the code:

```
class ItineraryViewontroller: UITableViewController {
....

         func clearAll(){

           var clearAlert = UIAlertView()
            clearAlert.delegate = self
            clearAlert.title = "Clear All"
            clearAlert.message = "Do you want to delete ALL events in itinerary?"
            clearAlert.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
            clearAlert.addButtonWithTitle("Cancel")
            clearAlert.show()

        }



        func alertView(View: UIAlertView!, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int){
            switch buttonIndex{

            case 0:
                NSLog("OK");

                 self.db.open()
                 self.db.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM bookmark",withArgumentsInArray: nil)

                 //self.tableView.delegate = self
                 //self.tableView.reloadData()
                 let selfClass =  ItineraryViewontroller()
                 selfClass.tableView.reloadData()


                break;
            case 1:
                NSLog("Cancel");
                break;
            default:
                NSLog("Default");
                break;
                //Some code here..

            }
        }
...
}
```

Comment: Have you also set `self.tableView.datasource = self`? Also set `self.tableView.datasource = self and self.tableView.delegate = self` in viewDidLoad.

Comment: yes, it is still not working for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    let selfClass =  ItineraryViewontroller()
     selfClass.tableView.reloadData()
```

These lines are not correct. You create a new **instance** of `ItineraryViewontroller`.

You should get the references of ItineraryViewontroller that is used to show your tableview.

Meanwhile,you have to update your `dataSource` of `tableview`

Comment: so, i have add the `self.tableView.reloadData()`,  is it correct? The purpose of `let selfClass = tineraryViewontroller()` is going to call itself again.

Comment: From the codes you post, I cannot figure out whether `self` is `ItineraryViewontroller`,if it is,you can try.

Comment: sorry for the missing information. I have tired to add the `self.tableView.reloadData()`, but it is not working.

Comment: You forget to update your `dataSource`, when clear data in DB, you also need to clear data of your tableview dataSource.

Comment: You are welcome.I will update the answer,so that others who meet with this problem can know what happens